how to stop the f5_cspm.wait_perf_data javascript function which is being called recurrently using setTimeout
The f5 loadbalancer is injecting this script to my index page:
<script id="f5_cspm">
(function () {
    var f5_cspm = {
        f5_p: 'someencodedtext',
        
        setCharAt: function (str, index, chr) {
            if (index > str.length - 1) return str;
            return str.substr(0, index) + chr + str.substr(index + 1);
        },
        
        get_byte: function (str, i) {
            var s = (i / 16) | 0;
            i = (i & 15);
            s = s * 32;
            return ((str.charCodeAt(i + 16 + s) - 65) << 4) | (str.charCodeAt(i + s) - 65);
        },
        
        set_byte: function (str, i, b) {
            var s = (i / 16) | 0;
            i = (i & 15);
            s = s * 32;
            str = f5_cspm.setCharAt(str, (i + 16 + s), String.fromCharCode((b >> 4) + 65));
            str = f5_cspm.setCharAt(str, (i + s), String.fromCharCode((b & 15) + 65));
            return str;
        },
        
        set_latency: function (str, latency) {
            latency = latency & 0xffff;
            str = f5_cspm.set_byte(str, 40, (latency >> 8));
            str = f5_cspm.set_byte(str, 41, (latency & 0xff));
            str = f5_cspm.set_byte(str, 35, 2);
            return str;
        },
        
        wait_perf_data: function () {
            try {
                var wp = window.performance.timing;
                if (wp.loadEventEnd > 0) {
                    var res = wp.loadEventEnd - wp.navigationStart;
                    if (res < 60001) {
                        var cookie_val = f5_cspm.set_latency(f5_cspm.f5_p, res);
                        window.document.cookie = 'f5avr0138950615aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_cspm_=' + encodeURIComponent(cookie_val) + ';path=/;' + '';
                    }
                    return;
                }
            } catch (err) {
                return;
            }
            setTimeout(f5_cspm.wait_perf_data, 100);
            return;
        },
        
        go: function () {
            var chunk = window.document.cookie.split(/\s*;\s*/);
            for (var i = 0; i < chunk.length; ++i) {
                var pair = chunk[i].split(/\s*=\s*/);
                if (pair[0] == 'f5_cspm' && pair[1] == '1234') {
                    var d = new Date();
                    d.setTime(d.getTime() - 1000);
                    window.document.cookie = 'f5_cspm=;expires=' + d.toUTCString() + ';path=/;' + ';';
                    setTimeout(f5_cspm.wait_perf_data, 100);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    f5_cspm.go();
}());
</script>

The reasoning why this is injected is described here: https://my.f5.com/manage/s/article/K13849
After the page loads I would like to use another script or even angular component and remove the <script id=f5_cspm"> and also stop the recurrent call for f5_cspm.wait_perf_data.
I was able to remove the script, but I dont know how to reach the recurent method.
When I try to find it using window.f5_cspm it returns undefined.
import { Injectable, Renderer2, RendererFactory2} from '@angular/core'; 

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'  // This makes the service available globally in the app
})

export class MyService {
    
    private renderer: Renderer2;

    constructor( private rendererFactory: RendererFactory2) { 
        this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
        this.removef5()
    }

    private removef5() {
        console.log('removef5  ');
        
        const scriptTag = document.getElementById("f5_cspm");
        if (scriptTag) {
            console.log("script will be removed: " + scriptTag); 
            this.renderer.removeChild(scriptTag.parentElement, scriptTag);  // Removes the script from the DOM
        }
         console.log('window.f5_cspm  ' + window.f5_cspm); // prints undefined 
    } 
}

